# is it possible to get html button clicked event out of the form tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i was wondering if we can get the events of a asp or html element out of the form tag ?
default.aspx :

```
<head runat="server">
<link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>test title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        this.
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <a id="aOnHtml" runat="server">Test</a>
        <button id="btnID" runat="server" onclick="btnClicked" > BTN </button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and default.aspx.cs :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnID.ServerClick += new EventHandler(this.btnClicked);

    }
    void btnClicked(Object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        aOnHtml.InnerText = "Clicked";
    }
}
```

i have break point at the begging of btnClicked function which it doesn't get there at all ,what is the problem ?

Comment: You don't have a form

Comment: Wrap your container div in the form .

Comment: if the button is not in the form it won't pass the clicked event to the server ? is that true ? if yes why is that ?!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the basic form element which you need to make this work.
Take a look at this :
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: that you need the <form> tag.

Comment: if the button is not in the form it won't pass the clicked event to the server ? is that true ? if yes why is that ?!!!!

Comment: Because that is the way it works, also for non asp.net you would need a form element.

Comment: give it a try and if it works please mark my answer.

Comment: OK , sorry i don't have access to the PC that i was coding with right now , i'll check it tomorrow and i will check the answer , but as i check the link that u posted I'm almost sure that its true , tnx

Answer (score 0):

what u have to do is :
1.  use `<asp:button>` instead of `<button>`
2. get `btnID.Click`or `btnID.ClientClick`instead of `btnID.ServerClick`
and everything will be fine .